# Haskell - heterogeneous arrays?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell with 99 Haskell problems :

https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems.
For one of the problems I have to return a heterogeneous array of `Element` and tuples of the form `(Int, Element)`. Since haskell doesn't allow storing heterogeneous data in array, the best I could come up with was

```
data Hetero a = Tuple (Int, a) | Elem a deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

then write my function like:

```
myFunk [a] -> [Hetero a] 

-- Rest of the function
```

But then my result looks something like this:

```
[Tuple (2, 10), Elem 1]
```

Is there a way I could modify my data type or function to return something like

```
[(2, 10), 1]
```

Comment: What would the type of `[(2, 10), 1]` be?

Comment: I see your point, think it should also be another user defined type

Comment: If you just want it to display nicely, you could map both to `String`, so that it'd become `["(2, 10)", "1"]`. You can't use the default instances of `show` for that, though, because (IIRC) it'd render `Tuple (2, 10)` as `"Tuple (2, 10)"`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann What I mean is, can I really store different data types in an array somehow. Something like you mentioned, defining an array type that stores tuples and elements. Instead of assigning elements of the array to a datatype

Comment: These 99 problems are nothing but trouble. They're really not written for Haskell. You've solved the problem; move on!

Comment: As @dfeuer writes, you've solved the problem. That's how it's done in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. What you've done already is the best and most idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, explicitly tagging which type each element has is the correct thing to do. This pays off when you actually want to *use* that list, because you can simply pattern match on the elements and then know in each clause for sure which types you have!

However, that doesn't mean such a list must always be *written out* with those verbose constructor names. You can save a lot of boilerplate by choosing different constructor names, in particular *infix constructors*:

```
data Hetero a = Int :* a | Elem a
```

Then your list looks like

```
[2 :* 10, Elem 1]
```

You could even allow defining those values by single numbers literals, by way of the instance

```
instance (Num a) => Num (Hetero a) where
  fromIntegral = Elem . fromIntegral
```

...which then allows writing

```
[2:*10, 1]
```

However this is probably not a good idea, because a `Num` type is also supposed to support addition, multiplication etc., which I'm not sure can be defined sensibly for the tuple case. If you go that route, you should make sure the arithmetic operations actually behave sanely.

Answer (score 0):

> But then my result *looks* something like this:

(my emphasis)

You can address that issue by changing the definition of `Hetero`:

```
data Hetero a = Tuple (Int, a) | Elem a deriving (Ord, Eq)

instance Show a => Show (Hetero a) where
  show (Tuple (i, x)) = "(" ++ show i ++ ", " ++ show x ++ ")"
  show (Elem x) = show x
```

Now a list of `Hetero` elements will look as you'd like it to look:

```
*Q46376603> [Tuple (2, 10), Elem 1]
[(2, 10),1]
```

Comment: This is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. The output of `show` is supposed to be valid Haskell code, but `[(2,10), 1]` is only valid if the elements really are plain tuples rather than `Hetero` values _and_ if you give these plain tuples a `Num` instance, which would pretty clearly be a bad idea.